# Module enchant nor found

Tags: python, enchant

I added pyenchant to my requirements files then
I tried adding this in my dockerfile (python version 3.10) (this worked on version 3.7 but not now):

```
RUN apt install --yes libenchant-2-2
```

```
RUN apt-get install -y gdebi
RUN curl -sLO http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/enchant/libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.1+b1_amd64.deb && gdebi -n libenchant1c2a_1.6.0-11.1+b1_amd64.deb
```

but i tried to import enchant got this error

```
No module named 'enchant'
```

And when i tried this

```
RUN apt install --yes libenchant1c2a
```

the error was files not found

Any idea how to install it  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should include your entire dockerfile including the specific base image. I was able to import enchant with this dockerfile.

You could replace the `CMD` line with something like `CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]` to run your file.

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.5-slim-buster

RUN apt update && apt install -y libenchant-dev
RUN pip install pyenchant
CMD ["python", "-c", "'import enchant'"]
```